# Activerecord error: Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, mysql2, puma

i've looked into previous questions which look similar to my problem, nothing seems to be related.
After doing the following query:

```
Runner::Models::Job.where(:id => job_id)
```

I get an exception, it happens once in a while:
Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SELECT  `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`  WHERE `jobs`.`id` = 7507 LIMIT 1

I use puma, and in config.ru i am using:

```
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
```

The thing is that this error always happens in the same place, and i cant figure out why is it happening, i've checked memory, cpu, etc'.., all seem normal.
Maybe someone will have an idea.
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your Resque task like this:

```
class MyTask
  def self.perform
    ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!
    # rest of your code
  end
end
```

see more details here: https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/FAQ#how-do-you-work-around-the-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-